# Hyperlinks slide new pages rather than opening them

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, slide

My manager asked me to try replicating the sliding feature here at this website:

https://insight.bakermckenzie.com/blockchains-and-laws

The navigator arrows at the right and left of the page direct the user to other pages of the site, but do so much like a carousel rather than simply opening the link in the traditional way.  Even hitting the browser's "back/forward" buttons makes the site slide between the pages rather than opening them normally.

I've dug through the source code and used the developer tools, but can't find out how exactly the site is pulling this off.  Any ideas?  Seems like it could be JavaScript, but I'm not too sure.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Looks like they used [readz.com](https://www.readz.com/). If you're more interested in the back button stuff you could look into the javascript history.pushState function.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the library that the site uses, but I'll try to explain it.
When you request a 'new page', by clicking on the arrows or the menu, all the content is loaded async. If you pay attention to the .page-container div, you can see that when you 'change' the page, the div with the content you are currently seeing moves to the side and then is completed removed from the page.

Step-by-step:

1. Request a page
2. New content loads into a div that is not visible yet.
3. The page you currently are moves to the side and then its content is removed when is completely hidden from the view (the whole html is deleted) .
4. The 'new page' that was requested follows the 'old' page movement.

It is like a carousel, but the new content is loaded async and the old one is removed.

[Div responsible for the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJZsW.png)

Comment: That's a neat trick.  I can't seem to find any kind of guidance anywhere on how to develop this.  I've built three simple pages with carousels, but I'm not sure how to get the arrows to link and load the other pages async as the example website I sent does.  Nor am I sure how to get the divs to move and load about like this.  Any ideas on where I can go to figure that one out?